# Cypress - "failed because you are mixing up async and sync code"

Tags: javascript, for-loop, recursion, cypress

I have a Cypress test that hits an API. that returns a list of items, I want it to essentially poll until I get the right reason (up to 30 times).

An example of what is returned is

```js
{
   "items":[
      {
         "reason":"incorrect"
      },
      {
         "reason":"correct"
      }
   ]
}
```

I have the following function that polls and returns the response if it gets the right reason returned. else it will throw an error

```js
function pollStatusReason(id, reason, attempts = 0) {
    const url = `http://someurl/${id}`;

    if (attempts > 30) throw `Too many attempts to get reason: ${reason}`;

    return cy.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
    }).then((response) => {
        if (response.status != 200) {
            pollStatusReason(id, reason, attempts + 1);
        } else {
            const items = response.body.items;
            for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                if (items[i].reason == reason) {
                    expect(reason).to.eq(items[i].reason);
                    return response
                } else {
                    cy.log('RETRYING TO GET STATUS REASON: ', reason);
                    cy.wait(5000); // Wait between attempts

                    pollStatusReason(id, reason, attempts + 1);
                }
            }
        };
    });
}

export default pollStatusReason;
```

And in the test I just call func

```
describe('Get items', () => {
  it('Get my items with the reason Correct', () => {
    pollStatusReason('123', 'correct').then((resp)=>{console.log(resp)})
  })
})
```

But it seems to be failing with

```
CypressError: `cy.then()` failed because you are mixing up async and sync code.
In your callback function you invoked 1 or more cy commands but then returned a synchronous value.
Cypress commands are asynchronous and it doesn't make sense to queue cy commands and yet return a synchronous value.
You likely forgot to properly chain the cy commands using another `cy.then()`.
The value you synchronously returned was: `Object{7}`
```

Weirdly enough, it doesn't fail all the time. But if anyone has any ideas, please let me know. I have a feeling to do with the for loop

Comment: I am no expert in cypress but don't you need to do `cy.wait(5000).then(() => pollStatusReason(id, reason, attempts + 1))`  to wait beetwen attempts ?

Answer (score 5):

Since the error complains that `return response` ***returned a synchronous value***, try to add `cy.wrap()` to overcome it.

```js
return cy.request({
  ...
  if (items[i].reason === reason) {   
    // get rid of expect() it's not needed
    return cy.wrap(response)
  }
  ...
```

Also you have seven items per response - that means the `else` part will fire `pollStatusReason` seven times which is not what you want

```js
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  if (...) {
  } else { 
    cy.wait(5000)
    // spawning too many recursions per request
    pollStatusReason(id, reason, attempts + 1)
```

Use a single expression to check the reason code e.g

```js
function pollStatusReason(id, expectedReason, attempts = 0) {
  ...
  return cy.request(...).then(response => {
    ...

    // get rid of for loop 
    const found = Cypress._.find(items, {'reason': expectedReason})

    if (found) {
      return cy.wrap(response)
    } else {
      cy.wait(5000)

      // return the recursion result and also put recursion call on the queue 
      // since you use cy.wait() above 
      return cy.then(() => pollStatusReason(id, reason, attempts + 1))
    }
```

Ref [lodash find](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#find)